# How to upgrade SQL Server 2005 Express instance to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express through command line arguments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using this command to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /q /ACTION=upgrade /INSTANCENAME=MyInstanceName /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1
```

but I am getting this error:

> Overall summary:
>   Final result: Failed: see details below
>   Exit code (Decimal):           -2067922429
>   Exit facility code:            1214
>   Exit error code:               515
>   Exit message:                  The CPU architectures of upgrading
>   feature(s) and this installation program are different. To upgrade
>   these features, Setup architecture must be the same as the features
>   being installed.
>   Start time:                    2012-12-11 16:51:45 
>   End time:                      2012-12-11 16:52:08
>   Requested action:              Upgrade
>
> Machine Properties:
>   Machine name:                  MARS-PC
>   Machine processor count:       1
>   OS version:                    Windows 7
>   OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
>   OS region:                     United States
>   OS language:                   English (United States)
>   **OS architecture:               x64**
>   **Process architecture:          64 Bit**
>   OS clustered:                  No

Answer (score 1):

The bit you've highlighted isn't the most relevant.

> The CPU architectures of upgrading feature(s) and this installation program are different.

That implies to me that the 2005 instance is a 32-bit install.

You'll need to uninstall 2005 (32-bit) and do a fresh install of 2008 (64-bit). Or detect bitness and use that to decide whether to perform a 32-bit or 64-bit upgrade.

Comment: If i try to install Sql server 2008 R2 installer for 32 bit machine .it gives error Exit message:                  SQL Server Setup is not supported in WOW64. This setup program can only be run on a 32-bit system.